# Python how to check and respond to a particular string in socket data?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to Python and would appreciate some help. My server receives any kind of data from the client. How can I modify the server code such that when it receives a certain string of text it responds with a particular string of text?

E.g. 
Client sends *101#
and Server responds with Hello World

but if the client sends *102#
Server would respond with Sorry

Thanks
Graham

Server

```
from socket import *

serverHost=''
serverport=50007

#open socket to listen 

sSock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
sSock.bind((serverHost,serverport))
sSock.listen(3)

#handle connection
while 1:
    conn,addr = sSock.accept()
    print ('Client Connection:', addr)
    while 1:
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        if not data: break
        print (' Server Received:', data)
        newData = data.replace('Client','Processed')
        conn.send(newData)

conn.close()
```

Client

```
import sys
from socket import  *

serverHost = 'localhost'
serverPort = 50007

message = ['*325#']

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    serverHost = sys.argv[1]

#create my socket
sSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)


#connect to server 
sSock.connect((serverHost, serverPort))


#send a message
for item in message:
    sSock.send(item)
    data = sSock.recv(1024)
    print ('Client received: ', 'data')

sSock.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, just take:

```
newData = data.replace('Client','Processed')
```

and replace it with something like:

```
if data == '*101#':
    newData = 'Hello World'
elif data == '*102#':
    newData = 'Sorry'
else:
    newData = data.replace('Client','Processed')
```

Not that this is optimal, but it should get you started.